# how to calculate(sum up) an a row value of an datatable

Tags: c#

i have an datatable like this.
i am getting this  data  from an excel sheet and  converted  to  datatable

```
id  workedhours  tfshours
1     3          2
2     5          5
3     .7         3
4      2         3.2
5     4.3       6.8
```

now i need  the  sum  of the column workedhours and  tfshours

how can i achive that is .there any builtin  function to get the sum of teh  column

i need  the  result like  this  in  a  new  datatable

```
 workedhours   tfshours
15                20
```

any help  would  be  greatly appreicated.
 thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a new Datatable and use the datatable.compute methods.

```
        DataTable sumDataTable = new DataTable();
        sumDataTable.Columns.Add("total", typeof(string));
        sumDataTable.Columns.Add("workedhours", typeof(int));
        sumDataTable.Columns.Add("tfshours", typeof(int));

        DataRow row = sumDataTable.NewRow();
        row["total"] = "Total";
        row["workedhours"] = oldDataTable.Compute("Sum(workedhours)", "workedhours > 0");
        row["tfshours"] = oldDataTable.Compute("Sum(tfshours)", "tfshours > 0");
        sumDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

The second parameter, filter, determines which rows are used in the expression, but you could just put "" to select all rows.

Comment: thanks Chris Anderson for  ur  Support.  

your  solution worked  great  for me.

Comment: @Chris Anderson will it work if i have a space in my column name ?

Comment: @user123456 it will work if you add braces `[column name with spaces]`

Answer (score 3):

There is buit-in method in DataTable object: DataTable.Compute

[MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using DataTable Methods:

```
decimal workedHours = (decimal)dataTable.Compute( "Sum(workedhours)", "" );   
decimal tfsHours = (decimal)dataTable.Compute( "Sum(tfshours)", "" );
```

Using Linq extensions:

```
decimal workedHours = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Sum( 
    row => decimal.Parse( row["workedhours"].ToString() ) );

decimal tfsHours = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Sum( 
    row => decimal.Parse( row["tfshours"].ToString() ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    DataTable sumDataTable = new DataTable();
    sumDataTable.Columns.Add("total", typeof(string));
    sumDataTable.Columns.Add("workedhours", typeof(int));
    sumDataTable.Columns.Add("tfshours", typeof(int));  

    DataRow row = sumDataTable .NewRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < sumDataTable .Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                        if(sumDataTable .Columns[j].Caption!="total")
                        row[j] = sumDataTable .Compute("Sum([" +                                
                        sumDataTable .Columns[j].Caption + "])", "");                       
                }
                sumDataTable .Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try LinQ (sorry, just VB but could easily transfered to C#):

```
Dim sum_workedhours = (From x in myDB Select x.workedhours).Sum()
```

Depending on your class you are using to save the database you may need to iterate the whole database... Maybe you would like to give us some more details